# Having Mercurial ignore everything except certain subdirectories

Tags: regex, mercurial

Through searching I've found how to have Mercurial ignore certain directories (and the files/directories they contain) *that are in the root of the repository directory*, but I can't work out how to extend this to *directories that are several levels in*.

In this case, I wish to only version control the following directories:

```
app/design/frontend/rc
skin/frontend/rc
```

As a result, my .hgignore file looks like this.

```
syntax=regexp
^(?!(app(/|$))|(skin(/|$)))
^app/code
^app/design/adminhtml
^app/design/frontend/base
^app/design/frontend/default
^app/design/install
^app/etc
^app/locale
^app/Mage.php
^app/.htaccess
^skin/adminhtml
^skin/frontend/base
^skin/frontend/default
^skin/install
```

I'm sure there's a much better way of doing it that doesn't involve picking out the other directories within app and skin, and as I'll probably want to do this for a few projects I thought I'd ask here. Thanks.

Comment: Nail has the right answer.  Don't muck w/ negative assertions in regex syntax, just ignore ".*" and then manually `hg add` the files you do want tracked. Add overrides `.hgignore`, so once you add them it's as if you crafted an unreadable exception in regexp.

Comment: Earlier when I was mucking about with the negative assertions it felt like I was so close, but it just didn't work with nested directories. If I can find out how to do it would save me manually adding the desired directories/files each time new files were added.

Comment: while updating my answer, I noticed a typo in your .hgignore.  It should be `syntax: regexp`, not `syntax=regexp`.

Comment: @Niall: Thanks. The syntax declaration seems to work as it is but I'll change it to conform to the proper standard.

Answer (score 3):

Manually add the directories that you want to your repository, then ignore everything else.

```
hg init
hg add app/design/frontend/rc
hg add skin/frontend/rc
```

Then in your .hgignore:

```
syntax: glob

**
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understand it, that would mean I have to manually add those directories/files each time new files were added which is why I'm still hoping I can get the negative assertion working.

Comment: @David Oliver he doesn't mean add them to the ignore file, he means add them to the repo in a commit. Mercurial doesn't automatically start tracking every file in a directory. It knows it's there but doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: @msarchet: Thanks, but I realise that. I'm trying to avoid having to explicitly tell Mercurial to add new files in directories I want to version control.

Comment: @David Oliver the ignore file tells the repo to pretend that the file doesn't exist. Is that basically what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it to ignore everything except two directories, which are not root directories.